# How to create an array of non-const C strings on the stack without repetitive code in C++03?

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm writing a unit test for a module that takes an array of mutable C strings in C++03 with [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html). The function argument is `char*const[]`. I want to create the arguments on the stack inside the function. My current solution is:

```
char args_stor[][1024] = {
    "parser",
    "-o",
    "SomeValue"
};
char* args[] = {
    args_stor[0],
    args_stor[1],
    args_stor[2]
};
```

How can I avoid the repetitive part, and if possible, transform it into one statement?

The function declaration is:

```
int getopt(int argc, char* const argv[], const char *optstring);
```

Use case is therefore:

```
getopt(3, args, ":o:");
```

Comment: Can't you just pass `args_stor` to your function? Please add a minimal example of how you want to use `args`.

Comment: use case would be getopt(3, args, ":o:");

Comment: oh I just recognized that getopt defines const for the pointer

Comment: replaced getopt with the function declaration that is used by the wrapping function

Comment: boost::mpl provides all the functionality of c++11 variadics in c++03

Comment: Why on the stack?

Comment: panic reaction to avoid bad reputation made me remove getopt from the question, reverted it back to the original after calming down and recognizing i was headless misreading the declaration

Comment: @n.m. see RAII (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like that (I added a `parse` function to verify the functionality):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parse(int argc, char* argv[], const char *optstring)
{
    printf("optstring = %s\n", optstring);
    printf("argv's:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("\t%s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char args_arr[][1024] = {
            "Hello",
            "how",
            "are",
            "you?"
        };
    char *args[sizeof args_arr / sizeof *args_arr];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof args / sizeof *args; ++i)
        args[i] = args_arr[i];

    parse(sizeof args / sizeof *args, args, ":o:");
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to add something, you only have to add it to the `args_arr` declaration. The `args` array will change accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can do that. `getopt`  requires `char * const[]`. The only improvement you can make is to use separate `char[]` declarations for each argument instead of the 2D array. This way you only allocate the needed space:

```
char opt1[] = "parser";
char opt2[] = "-o";
char *args[] = { opt1, opt2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments to the question, it's not vital that the char array be allocated *on the stack*, only that it is correctly and automatically *cleaned up* after use, so that we can invoke the function something like this:

```
void f(char *const *args);

int main()
{
    const char *args[] = {
        "parser",
        "-o",
        "SomeValue"
    };
    f(transform(args)->p);
}
```

To implement `transform()`, we can return a `std::auto_ptr` to a suitable structure:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

template<std::size_t N>
struct arg_list
{
    char *s;        // string storage
    char *p[N+1];   // pointers into s

    arg_list(const char *const *args)
        : s(new char[total_len(args)]), p()
    {
        char *dest = s;
        for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < N;  ++i) {
            std::strcpy(p[i] = dest, args[i]);
            dest += std::strlen(args[i]) + 1;
        }
        p[N] = 0;
    }

    ~arg_list() { delete[] s; }

    static std::size_t total_len(const char *const *args) {
        std::size_t length = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < N;  ++i)
            length += std::strlen(args[i]) + 1;
        return length;
    }
};

template<std::size_t N>
std::auto_ptr< arg_list<N> > transform(const char *const (&args)[N])
{
    return std::auto_ptr< arg_list<N> >(new arg_list<N>(args));
}
```

The `arg_list` object will be destroyed after the call to `f()` in `main()`.  We can test it, using this example `f()`:

```
#include <iostream>
void f(char *const *args)
{
    while (*args)
        std::cout << *args++ << std::endl;
}
```

No memory is leaked, and no accesses are made to invalid memory:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./44908185 
==23361== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23361== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23361== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23361== Command: ./44908185
==23361==  
parser
-o
SomeValue
==23361== 
==23361== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23361==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23361==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 72,764 bytes allocated
```

There are easier versions of this for newer standards of C++, but this seems to be the simplest in C++03.

Answer (score -1):

how about this?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char *what[] = {"asd", "asd", "asd"};
}
```

Comment: A quick explication why this code is better may make this a better answer.

Comment: This example will not compile in C++, string literals are not compatible with `char *`. The error is something like `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`.

Comment: This is a bad solution. On my computer, `int main() { char *a = "a"; a[0] = 'b'; }` crashes. So this solution can crash too.